# business day not calculating correctly

Tags: apex

I am using a trigger to calculate business days (skipping weekends and holidays).  I'm getting correct results sometimes and incorrect results other times, so my code is not calculating correct.

Here are two trigger classes that where I'm calculating non-business days and holidaysI have:

```
global class SalesOrderSetEstDeliveryDate implements ITriggers.HandlerInterface {

SalesOrder__c[] newCollection = trigger.new;

global void handle() {
    if(!RecursionBlocker.salesOrderSetEstDeliveryDateFirstCall) {
        RecursionBlocker.salesOrderSetEstDeliveryDateFirstCall = true;
        setEstDeliveryDate();
    }       
}

private void setEstDeliveryDate() {
    Map<Date, DateTime> mapHolidays = LibCommonFunctions.getHolidayList();
    List<SalesOrder__c> recordsToUpdate = new List<SalesOrder__c>();
    List<SalesOrder__c> orders = [select Ship_Due_Date__c, Transit_Days__c from SalesOrder__c where Id in: newCollection];
    for(SalesOrder__c so : orders) {
        Integer transitDays = so.Transit_Days__c.intValue();
        so.Est_Delivery_Date__c = LibCommonFunctions.addBusinessDays(so.Ship_Due_Date__c, mapHolidays, transitDays);
        recordsToUpdate.add(so);            
    }
    if(!recordsToUpdate.isEmpty() && recordsToUpdate.size() > 0) {
        update recordsToUpdate;
    }   
}
}

global class SalesOrderSetShipDueDate implements ITriggers.HandlerInterface {

SalesOrder__c[] newCollection = trigger.new;

global void handle() {
    if(!RecursionBlocker.salesOrderSetShipDueDateFirstCall) {
        RecursionBlocker.salesOrderSetShipDueDateFirstCall = true;
        setShipDueDate();
    }       
}

private void setShipDueDate() {
    Map<Date, DateTime> mapHolidays = LibCommonFunctions.getHolidayList();
    List<SalesOrder__c> recordsToUpdate = new List<SalesOrder__c>();
    List<SalesOrder__c> orders = [select Ship_Due_Date__c, Hard_in_Hands_Date__c, Transit_Days__c, Date_Order_Placed__c, Total_Turnaround__c from SalesOrder__c where Id in: newCollection];
    for(SalesOrder__c so : orders) {
        Integer transitDays = so.Transit_Days__c.intValue();
        Integer totalTurnaround = so.Total_Turnaround__c.intValue();
        if(so.Hard_In_Hands_Date__c != null && LibCommonFunctions.addBusinessDays(so.Hard_In_Hands_Date__c, mapHolidays, -transitDays) < LibCommonFunctions.addBusinessDays(so.Date_Order_Placed__c, mapHolidays, totalTurnaround)) {
            so.Ship_Due_Date__c = LibCommonFunctions.addBusinessDays(so.Hard_In_Hands_Date__c, mapHolidays, -transitDays);
            recordsToUpdate.add(so);
        }
        else {
            so.Ship_Due_Date__c = LibCommonFunctions.addBusinessDays(so.Date_Order_Placed__c, mapHolidays, totalTurnaround);
            recordsToUpdate.add(so);                    
        }
    }
    if(!recordsToUpdate.isEmpty() && recordsToUpdate.size() > 0) {
        update recordsToUpdate;
    }
}
}
```

Here are my methods in a utility class:

```
public static Date addBusinessDays(Date d, map<Date, DateTime> mapholidays, integer DayDifference)
{
    if(DayDifference > 0)
    {
        integer counter = DayDifference;
        for(integer i = 1; i <= counter; i++) {
            DateTime dt = DateTime.newInstance(d.addDays(i), Time.newInstance(0, 0, 0, 0));
            String dayOfWeek = dt.format('EEEE');
            if(dayOfWeek.toUpperCase() == 'SATURDAY' || dayOfWeek.toUpperCase() == 'SUNDAY' || mapholidays.containsKey(d.addDays(i)))
            {
                counter++;
            }
        }
        return d.addDays(counter);
    }
    else
    {
        integer counter = DayDifference;
        for(integer i = -1; i >= counter; i--)
        {
            DateTime dt = DateTime.newInstance(d.addDays(i), Time.newInstance(0, 0, 0, 0));
            String dayOfWeek = dt.format('EEEE');
            if(dayOfWeek.toUpperCase() == 'SATURDAY' || dayOfWeek.toUpperCase() == 'SUNDAY' || mapholidays.containsKey(d.addDays(i))) {
                counter--;
            }
        }
        return d.addDays(counter);

    }
    return null;
}

public static Map<Date, DateTime> getHolidayList() {
    Map<Date, DateTime> mapHolidays = new Map<Date, DateTime>();
    if(holidaysCacheLoaded) return mapHolidays;
    for(Holiday objH : [select id,ActivityDate,Name, RecurrenceType, RecurrenceStartDate, RecurrenceMonthOfYear, RecurrenceInstance, RecurrenceDayOfWeekMask, IsRecurrence, IsAllDay from Holiday]) {
        mapHolidays.put(Date.newInstance((objH.ActivityDate).year(),(objH.ActivityDate).month(),(objH.ActivityDate).day()),objH.ActivityDate);
    }
    holidaysCacheLoaded = true;
    return mapHolidays;
}
```

I've refactored several times now and almost have it working exactly as I want.  I'm encountering one weird issue with a December holiday.  The week of Christmas is a full holiday off from the 22nd to the 26th.  If I enter a Date Order Placed of 12/1/2014, the Ship Due Date is set to 12/19/2014, which is correct. But, the Est Delivery Date is showing as 12/22/2014, which is not correct because the 22nd is a holiday.  But, if I change the Date Order Placed by one day to 12/2/2014, the Ship Due Date is set to 12/29/2014, which is correct and the Est Delivery Date is 12/30,/2014, which is also correct.  It skips the holidays for the week of Christmas correctly.  Not sure why it is missing the holidays when I set the Date Order Placed on 12/1/2014???  I haven't found the error.

Any help would be appreciated.
Thanks.

Comment: How about using standard salesforce functionality provided by BusinessHours class ? see the following please https://www.salesforce.com/us/developer/docs/apexcode/Content/apex_classes_businesshours.htm

Comment: I am using the BusinessHours class to calculate the BusinessDays.  I'm also using the Holiday class.  I had the business days working correctly up until I implemented the Holidays and then I started getting incorrect results.  I'm not sure where the issue is with the Holiday calculation.  Thanks.

Comment: Did you even look at the reference @ManSpan cited? It takes into account the holidays your org uses. You're reinventing the wheel.

Comment: @crmprogdev I've refactored my code (see above).  I'm using the BusinessHours class, specifically `isWithin()` to skip weekends and holidays, but my calculation is still off.  I haven't been able to see why it is including weekends and/or holidays.  Any help you can provide is appreciated.  Thank you.

Comment: @Dman100 - Did you associate the holidays with the business hours (relaeted list on holiday or business hours)?

Comment: @Eric The Holidays are a related list on the Business Hours.  I've refactored my code again (see changes above).  It is almost working exactly as I want, but I have one weird problem occurring.  See my description of the bug in my original post that I've edited.

Comment: @Dman100 - It is tough to diagnose BUT it may be due to GMT and date time conversions used by the system and depending on the methods you use to create the date.....I remember doing this once before and I found that the issue was due to that. Use a lot of debugs to debug the dates/times and differences between the holiday and the dates you are using. Use hours not days to debug